# Android: How to force a request to use WAP

Tags: android, wap

On Android, is there a way to force a particular request to go through WAP instead of wifi?

I want to leave wifi turned on, so that it can continue to be used for other connections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi)

Comment: Thanks Dave. This is a good workaround. But turning the wi-fi off/on might cause other problems. If another process is doing background downloading, their wi-fi usage will be interrupted. Is it not possible to do this without switching wi-fi?

Answer (score 0):

The 'possible duplicate' answer has been updated since this post was originally made.  From Android 2.2 onwards it would appear to be possible to turn on the WAP connection and then start using it for a particular connection.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi/4756630#4756630).