# How to use mobile data forcefully for any application when wifi is on in Android 6

Tags: android, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, cellular-network, android-connectivitymanager

I want the android application to **use only mobile data even if WIFI and mobile data both on** in **Android 6**. How can I bind the android process to Mobile data only.
Please suggest. Examples will be good.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this pretty easy if you're android version is M or above.
First, you need the right manifest permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

Here is an example method that should do what you need:

```
public static void forceConnectionToMobile2(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connection_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

        Log.d(TAG,"request TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
        request.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

        connection_manager.requestNetwork(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"binding app to cellular network");
                    connection_manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with wifi having no internet and turning on cellular data, but i am not able to use internet then...

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean mobileDataEnabled = false;

        try {
            Class cmClass = Class.forName(connection_manager.getClass().getName());
            Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) method.invoke(connection_manager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
First check if mobile data enable or disable then do 

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
            request.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);

            connection_manager.requestNetwork(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
connection_manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Android force app to use mobile data channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086044/android-force-app-to-use-mobile-data-channel)

```
    manager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if(manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    manager.setWifiEnabled(false);
}
// and to be sure:
ConnectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Comment: I dont want to _disable WIFI in the device level_. just want to use **mobile data only** for my app.

Comment: boolean mobileDataEnabled = false;

        try {
            Class cmClass = Class.forName(connection_manager.getClass().getName());
            Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) method.invoke(connection_manager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }