# Simple speed test app on Android suggestions

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, wifi

Can anyone point me to any sample code which explains (even slightly) how to write a simple wifi speedtest program for Android? I have looked everywhere!

Thanks in advance!

-Michael

Comment: Do you want to test the speed of the WiFi to which the Android device is connected?

Comment: @rodolk That is correct! I would also want to test the speed of the 4g/3g, but that can be a question for another post :D

Comment: I'm trying to understand the level of deepness your intend. Are you thinking about using http to get to a server and obtain the whole round trip time or you want to go down to the kernel and measure low-level layer-2 messages?

Comment: @rodolk As I am just get started with Android and networking, I would want the high level ping to server, download file, measure the total bits transferred and time, etc. At one point I would want to do the low-level stuff, but my priority is high level. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a response with some suggestions that could help you. Let me know if it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy. Let me give you some suggestions but you will need to investigate more.

I'm not sure whether it is possible to access low level metrics of the WiFi connection or a 3G connection. Supposing it's not possible, my suggestions are oriented to use a ping or a ping-similar solution with some server and obtain the round-trip time (RTT).

Now, when you connect to a server, there are many factors affecting the RTT, these are the main ones:

- WiFi speed, congestion, and communication errors
- Latency in the whole path to the server, including ISP capacity and backbones.
- Congestion in the path
- Server speed to respond

Usually you execute a ping to test reachability and a taste of RTT. Ping is implemented with ICMP Echo Request. However, Java does not provide the means to send an ICMP message. So you might try to establish a TCP connection to some server.

You could use InetAddress::isReachable with a timeout various times until you find out the limit timeout. I wouldn't recommend this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)

I would create a TCP socket and call connect and then determine the time it took since connect was called. Of course you have to deal with all factors that affect speed.

Another point to consider is that if you use connect in a TCP socket, you have to understand that there is actually a three-way handshake: client sends a SYNC, server sends SYN/ACK, client sends ACK. But this last ACK doesn't add significant time to the return of connect because it's just sent by the client.

Having said that, I'll go with some suggestions:

First thing I would try, only with a WiFi, is trying to establish a connection to the access point, to port 80, 8080 or 443. That would eliminate other the last three factors.

If it doesn't work you could try a fix server, www.google.com for example. In this case you will have to deal with all the mentioned factors.

In the case of 3G, I don't know how you  could could establish  a connection to the access point like a Gateway GPRS Support Node in UMTS. But you can connect to a fix server, considering all 4 factors mentioned above.

Other point to consider si that when the smartphone has connectivity to WiFi and Cellular, it always uses WiFi. There are ways to force it to use 3g though, some links:
[Android: Force data to be sent over radio vs WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883777/android-force-data-to-be-sent-over-radio-vs-wifi)
[Force Android to use 3G when on local area wifi without net access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844846/force-android-to-use-3g-when-on-local-area-wifi-without-net-access)

I hope this helps.