# Enable/disable data connection in android programmatically

Tags: android, gprs, invocationtargetexception

I want to enable/disable the data connection programmatically. I've used the following code:

```
void enableInternet(boolean yes)
{
    ConnectivityManager iMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Method iMthd = null;
    try {
        iMthd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
               } 
    iMthd.setAccessible(false);

    if(yes)
     {

                try {
                    iMthd.invoke(iMgr, true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data connection Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     dataButton.setChecked(false);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IllegalArgumentException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IllegalAccessException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     dataButton.setChecked(false);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "InvocationTargetException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

     }
    else
     {
        try {
            iMthd.invoke(iMgr, true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data connection Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   dataButton.setChecked(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Disabling Data connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
     }
}
```

It's working without any errors in the emulator but, I'm getting "InvocationTargetException" when I try to run it on a real device.
I'm using API level 8 to build the application.

Comment: What is the result of `e.getMessage()` on the `InvocationTargetException`? How about the enclosed exception?

Comment: What device are you running this on and what version of Android OS is installed on that device.

Comment: I'm running it on a Samsung Galaxy S and the Android OS is 2.2

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This code sample should work for android phones running gingerbread and higher:

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

Dont forget to add this line to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: what parameter need to send data enable and data disable?

Comment: I got java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error after run this code.

Comment: @ReferenceNotFound Are you sure you added the permission? 11 other people or more got i working, including me.

Comment: Thanks for reply but, I have already add permission and I am using Android 2.2

Comment: That is why it doesn't work. This workaround only works for Gingerbread and higher, which means you have to be on Android 2.3 or higher. Sorry!

Comment: For android versions less than 2.3 we can use the java reflection method to enable/disable data connection. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662978/how-to-provide-option-to-select-wi-fi-or-gprs-for-network-connectivity-in-android.

Comment: +1, your method worked very well for me. Thanks, is there anyway I can set GPS on Off programmatically same as you did Internet on/off programmatically like above ?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen I tried adding this code in the AppWidgetProvider OnReceive method but I am getting **W/ActivityManager(444): Killing ProcessRecord{a6bdce00 1809:com.rajaraman.quicksettings/u0a10064}: background ANR** Do I have to run this in a thread to avoid ANR?

Comment: Running this in AsyncTask does not throw background ANR.

Comment: Can someone tell me what other changes are required with using the code... like namespaces that need to be imported, etc...

Comment: I have a theoretical doubt. Is the above code an example of the usage of *reflection*? If not, then what do you call such a method employed here as?

Comment: Confirmed working on 4.4.2. However, lines 4-7 seem redundant as we already have a ConnectivityManager object. Is there any meaning to this?

Comment: For line `Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());` I have got a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. How to solve it ?

Comment: What is the phone is dual sim?

Comment: Does it turn off the radio connection (GSM) too ?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean]

Comment: @PrakashSharma The method or Api might have been deprecated. PLease consider that this post is from 2012.

Answer (score 1):

@riHaN JiTHiN your program works fine for 2.3 and above, But it needs a small change in 'else' statement:

```
else
     {
        try {
            iMthd.invoke(iMgr, true);
```

the 'true' should be changed to 'false'

```
iMthd.invoke(iMgr, false);
```