# How to Disable data connection programmatically in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable/disable data connection in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)

Need a solution for disabling of mobile data connection programmatically in android to stop the internet connectivity .

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not a good idea, instead you should ask your users to disable this option manually by firing a correspondent `Intent` from [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) list of actions. Hope this helps.