# Enable data connection on android system app

Tags: android, 3g

I'm trying to make a android **system** app (for me and friends), to let me control my android phone over my server. 
Actually I've problem to enable/disable data connection. When I search, I found topic that said there is no possibility, or giving a no longer supported way (by using breach). This was exactly the same for GPS controle, but I found a way because my app is a system app.

So I want to know if someone know a way to enable and disable data connection without user consent on a system app. I didn't find anything on the api.

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at my post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically/11555457#11555457

Comment: Thank for your answer, I see it before, but when I try, it didn't work. I try again and I ask you after if i've still problem to use it.

Comment: Remember, as I said in that post, you have to run gingerbread and higher. 18 other people have succeeded using this method.

Comment: It work ! I was importing the wrong "field", but on the doc, i read that the good one is "java.lang.reflect.Field". And I need to add a try/catch, and finally at the end I forgot (like an idiot) to add the permission.. Thank for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't : i've not enough reputation