# Disable/Enabling mobile data programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to enable/disable mobile data.

First, is it possible to implement this?

I am gone through the below link

[How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

[Enable/disable data connection in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)

But I am not getting the right way to implement this.

Getting InvocationTargetException and not able to add MODIFY_PHONE_STATE also in android manifest file as it is a system-only permission.

And from forum I came to know that it was deprecated after Gingerbread.

How do I need to implement this?

Comment: did you added these permissions `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"`

Comment: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE cannot be used by third party apps. Check this documentation.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Users would not like this behavior and its not possible without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks to Arash & shruti :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to enable/disable mobile data.
>
> First, is it possible to implement this?

No, that's not possible to achieve by third-party apps. Enabling/disabling mobile data should be done through system Settings app UI.

What you can do is to provide an instruction to end user on how to enable/disable mobile data and direct them to Settings app.