# setting only 2G in android app

Tags: android

I understand from any posts that this kind of functionality is not possible in an app.
But there are many posts(meant for different functionality though like data enable/disable ([Enable/disable data connection in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)) ) which uses java reflection method to access some of the internal classes.methods.

I wanted to control this rat settings from application. Is it possible to use reflection and what API should be used for such thing?
I also want to know if usage of reflect is acceptable in an app?

Thanks,
/Hvr