# Permanently disable mobile data connections in Android

Tags: android

How can I permanently disable mobile data connections in Android?

I know I can turn this on and off in the menu, but what I want is to permanently make it impossible.for anyone to turn this on, for example.by deleting a necessary file (similar to deleting IO80211Family.kext on a Mac).

At the same time, I want to retain the possibility to connect via WLAN.

Please provide an idiot level explanation.

Comment: Remove the SIM card?

Comment: Does WLAN still work,  and can I still make phone calls, after removing the SIM card?

Answer (score 2):

"Please provide an idiot level explanation." I can not do this, because SO is not allowing it.

About solution to your problem,

**Step-1 :** Register receiver with android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action in manifest.

**Step-2 :** onReceive method of broadcastreceiver, check for the type of internet connection Data connection / WLAN.

Ref : [Android: Internet connectivity change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener)

**Step-3 :** Disable data connection programmatically

Ref : [Enable/disable data connection in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not permanent, because I need nothing to undo it but the phone itself. (Whereas the solution on the Mac cannot be undone without at least a data storage device, because an essential file was deleted.)