# Application is not working when network switches

Tags: android, https

My android application is working fine while making `https` request in `2G connection`. But unable to connect in `3G network`. I am not able to find out problem behind it.

Comment: Your 3G Provider might limit or modifiy your connection ability? (I've seen live-compressing and mangling of content...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try added permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And study this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi)

Comment: I have missed out this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />.