# android connect to server via 3g not wifi

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I am looking to create an application that sends a live video stream from a phone to be stored on a server, using 3g.

I found [spydroid](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) which is very similar to what I want to do.  Looking through the code I just realised it uses wifi not 3g.

My question is what do I need to change so that it uses 3g instead of wifi?  (I'm looking for general pointers, I don't want you to look through the actual code :) )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of:
[How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi). Look at teh answer that got the best score.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I looked through that question, and it addresses choosing 3g or wifi from within your app.  What I'm looking for is how to actually communicate (send the live video stream) over 3g, as wifi won't be available in most situations where the app will be used.