# RequestRouteToHost doesn't work

Tags: android, routes, mms, connectivity

I need to check if the route to host exists for my Android app. Here is my code:

```
private void ensureRouteToHost(String proxyAddr) throws IOException
{
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    int inetAddr;
    inetAddr = lookupHost(proxyAddr); // Return -938825536 for IP 192.168.10.200
    Log.d(TAG, "host for proxy is " + inetAddr);
    if (inetAddr == -1)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "cannot establish route for " + proxyAddr + ": unkown host");
        throw new IOException("Cannot establish route for " + proxyAddr + ": Unknown host");
    }
    else
    {
        int[] apnTypes = new int[] {ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL};
        for (int i=0; i<apnTypes.length; i++)
        {
            if (connMgr.requestRouteToHost(apnTypes[i], inetAddr))
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "route to host requested");
                return;
            }
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "unable to request route to host");
        throw new IOException("Cannot establish route to proxy " + inetAddr);
    }
}

public static int lookupHost(String hostname)
{
    hostname = hostname.substring(0, hostname.indexOf(":") > 0 ? hostname.indexOf(":") : hostname.length());
    String result = "";
    String[] array = hostname.split("\\.");
    if (array.length != 4) return -1;

    int[] hexArray = new int[] {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    hexArray[0] = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) / 16;
    hexArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) % 16;
    hexArray[2] = Integer.parseInt(array[1]) / 16;
    hexArray[3] = Integer.parseInt(array[1]) % 16;
    hexArray[4] = Integer.parseInt(array[2]) / 16;
    hexArray[5] = Integer.parseInt(array[2]) % 16;
    hexArray[6] = Integer.parseInt(array[3]) / 16;
    hexArray[7] = Integer.parseInt(array[3]) % 16;

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        result += Integer.toHexString( hexArray[i] );
    }

    return Long.valueOf(Long.parseLong(result, 16)).intValue();
}
```

It works perfectly on most devices but, and that's really weird, it doesn't work on Nexus S Europe. I've tried a couple of Nexus and I always got that problem.
The problem is located in the `ensureRouteToHost` method when I call `connMgr.requestRouteToHost(apnTypes[i], inetAddr)`. It always returns false, whatever I put in. My plan is to check if the IP `192.168.10.200` is reachable or not for my MMS App. **This doesn't work neither for public IP such as stackoverflow.com (69.59.197.21 or 1161544981 as int).**

So, do you have an idea why this isn't working on some devices ?
Thanks for reading my thread.

Comment: Your code work on a Galaxy Nexus GSM (CyanogenMod 10), with the TYPE_MOBILE (and obviously only if the mobile data connection is enabled)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It works too on Xperia T 4.0.3, Desire S 4.0.4, Galaxy S3 4.1, Huawei Ascend P1 4.0.3, etc... The troubles appear under Nexus S europe version 4.0.3. Data is enabled on all devices. Changing SIM cards doesn't solved the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.
It can't find the route to IP with the wifi on. Simplest way is to disable wifi, do your stuff and then enable wifi.

Here is the code I used:

```
// Disable wifi if it's active
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
{
      mWasWifiActive = true;
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
      Log.e(TAG, "Wifi was enabled, now Off.");
}

// Do stuff here

// Re-enable wifi if it was active before routing
if (mWasWifiActive)
{
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
       Log.e(TAG, "Wifi is back online.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring up those interfaces, e.g. HIPRI, first. The way to do that is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi/4756630#4756630).

However I find that whilst this makes both interfaces come up, and `requestRouteToHost` return true (at least, once the network is actually up), the routing still appears to have no effect.

This is as tested on a number of different phones.

Please let me know if you succeed with this.