# Android: any way around the HIPRI connection type timeout?

Tags: android, networking, telephony

You can use the TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI network type in order to force connections to a particular host to go over the mobile connection rather than wifi, as described in Rainbowbreeze's answer here: [How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi/4756630#4756630). Unfortunately, the system enforces a timeout on these connections which is too short for my application, meaning it is effectively useless to me.  Is there some way of cancelling this timeout, or another way of achieving the same results?  If it helps, I am happy to restrict my application to running on rooted phones only.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by refreshing hipri connection after every 50 sec.The system time out for a hipri connection is 1 min.So call 'enableHipri' after every 50sec.

Comment: That's going to kill battery, though.  My application for HIPRI is to enable long-lived instant notifications on a phone that doesn't do wake-on-wlan but does do wake-on-mobile-date, so if I were going to wake up every 50 seconds (which means the phone will basically never go into full sleep mode) I could just use a wakelock and keep the wireless active all the time instead.