# Jointly receive data through Wifi and Cell GSM in Android?

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I'm wondering if Android allows applications to jointly receive data through the Wifi and Cell GSM. I need to develop an application that have to receive internet data through the GSM and some local data through Wifi while maintaining both the network connectivity. Is this possible to do ?

Comment: Yes it is, as long as your connections are alive of course.

Answer (score 1):

While connected to Wi-Fi, you can ask the system to **temporarily** pass traffic to a **specific host** via cell connection.

This is done by a mode called "HIPRI" (High Priority).

The HIPRI uses the cell radio, but logically it is a different connection type than cell. This means that although your communication would be done via the cell, the cell connection would still be unavailable for other purposes.

A good example can be found here (answer by Rainbowbreeze):

[How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi).