# Android: Force on Data Network if Wifi is on.Works on GSM fails CDMA Devices

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, gsm, cdma

On GSM devices able to [force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi/4756630#4756630) on data network if wifi is on ,But on CDMA devcies it fails.

```
public boolean isMobileHighPriorityUP() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mCxt.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        State mobileHigh = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI).getState();
        Log.d(TAG, "--------- Network HIPRI State --------" + mobileHigh);
        if(mobileHigh == State.CONNECTED){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Above always return false on CDMA but on GSM true..

Found [enableHIPRI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/Phone.java#Phone.0FEATURE_ENABLE_HIPRI) here on Phone Interface firmware code.

Assuming [Phonebase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneBase.java#PhoneBase) is used for GSM, and  [CDMAPhonebase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/CDMAPhone.java#CDMAPhone) is used for CDMA which extends PhoneBase.

Could not find much info on the firmware codes above and [code1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature%28int,java.lang.String%29) [code2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/net/IConnectivityManager.java#IConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature%28int,java.lang.String,android.os.IBinder%29).
Is CDMA firmware has some other design applied?Can you guys throw some light here.?

Thanks

NitZ

Answer (score 1):

```
int resultInt = connMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableHIPRI");
```

Will return -1 if the device doesn't support HiPri; you have to fall back to forcing the 3g / 4g connection by turning off the wifi (and returning it to its previous state once you've finished).

Can't remember if all CDMA devices don't support HiPri, but it might be the device you're testing on?

Comment: resultInt value might be -1(will get back on this), Want to known the reason for the same why it fails on CDMA."Turning off the wifi (and returning it to its previous state once you've finished)."I cant do this as i am opposing the user action.Please move this to comments section.