# Force our app to use 2G/3G over WiFi using NetworkRequest api?

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I need the sample code to use NetworkRequest api so that my app can use 2G/3G instead of WiFi.

Comment: whats the basic idea to use 2g/3g over wifi

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate question [How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi)

In the above given link @Rainbowbreeze has given a code snippet to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But he was not using "NetworkRequest api". This not duplicate question. Please read question carefully