# Creating two sockets at client side android app

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

Hi I am new to socket programming.I am developing a client- server application. My server will a Java application. My client will be an android App. what i want to do is that i want to send data over both the channels i.e WiFi and 3G network. Is this Possible to send some packets over WiFi and some over 3G.
Is  such a mechanism possible. If yes how can i accomplish this?

what I thought that i will create two sockets at client side and bind them to their specific IP's i.e bind one socket with wifi IP and other with 3G network IP.
Is there any provision of binding IP's with sockets at client side.

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi/4756630#4756630

Comment: I want to use both the networks at the same time in that example it is only using 3G