# How to use 4G network from ConnectivityManager for Chrome CustomTab?

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am replacing **Webview** with **Chrome CustomTab** in android application, using ConnectivityManager class i was able to send traffic though 4G/ Mobile Network in Webview.

Something similar to this post- [How to use 3G Connection in Android Application instead of Wi-fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513713/how-to-use-3g-connection-in-android-application-instead-of-wi-fi)

Now when using Custom Chrome TAB i want to do same - ConnectivityManager switches network to MOBILE network before making network call, but looks like same approach is not doing our work.

Appreciate your help here.

Thanks

Comment: Since Chrome custom tabs are not implemented in your app, I doubt that you can control this. Chrome will do what Chrome wants to do.

Comment: Right, Only approach here i can think is Turn off the Wifi before call (not ideal thing to do) and turn it back on. Thanks for reply @CommonsWare.